# Does Resources.Load() return a unique object every time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, Let's say I load the same prefab file several times using `Resources.Load("PrefabName")`. (*I assign each call to a different variable, of course.*)

Do I get multiple objects or just multiple references to a single object?

Comment: You can check this with [Object.ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling Resources.Load() on a prefab will return a reference to the asset, which should always reference the same asset. What Resources.Load() returns isn't an ingame object, and can't be placed ingame unless you call [Instantiate(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)  for it. Instantiate in turn will create the gameobject ingame and then return a reference to it. Obviously each instantiate is a unique/new gameobject.

It is also possible to destroy the asset (With GameObject.DestroyImmediate if I remember right), but that's not usually the best of ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to create an object that doesn't appear in the game using Instantiate? I need to create many *separate* "blueprint" objects from the same prefab. These will be used to instantiate in-game objects, but the blueprints themselves shouldn't appear in game.

Comment: Hmm... well you could probably save a bunch of different references to the asset. These won't appear ingame until you call instantiate.